# sql query is only updating first match

Tags: mysql

I have an update query which i thought should update multiple rows in one request..

```
UPDATE myTable SET val = val + 1 WHERE id = "X" or "Y"
```

however this only seems to update X's val not Y's as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET val = val + 1 
WHERE id = 'X' 
   OR id = 'Y'
```

or

```
WHERE id in ('X', 'Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query works fine, but will ignore "Y" values because it will be evaluated as:

```
UPDATE myTable SET val = val + 1 WHERE id = "X" or FALSE
```

because "Y" will be evaluated as 0 which is false.

You have to fix your where condition to

```
(id = "X" or id = "Y")
```